# How to use @HostListener when location.hash changed? (angular 2)

Tags: angular, typescript, window, location

I am trying to call some function every time, when url changes.

```
@HostListener('window:hashchanged', ['$event'])
  someFunction(event) {
  console.log('test')
}
```

How i can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event is `hashchange` withaout the `d` at the end:

```
@HostListener('window:hashchange', ['$event'])
```

Comment: Does `window.addEventListener('hashchange', (e) => console.log(e))` work? Maybe the event is not fired.

Comment: Maybe i can trigger this by another way?

Comment: What do you mean by trigger? Have you tried `window.addEventListener()`? If this doesn't work it's unlikely there is such an event fired at all.

Comment: I want call some function every time, when URL changed.